# Volume of simplex - looking for a clever transformation of variables

Tags: integration, measure-theory, volume, change-of-variable, simplex

I am formulating the elementary simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ as $\{(x_1,..,x_n):0\leq x_i\leq 1,\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i<1\}$. Correspondingly, its volume $V$ should be equal to ($\mathbb 1_A$ is the indicator function over $A$):
$$ V=\int_0^1\text d x_1..\int_0^1\text dx_n \mathbb 1_{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i<1}. $$

Normally, this integral is written under the form:
$$ V=\int_0^1\text d y_1..\int_0^{y_{n-1}}\text dy_n=\frac 1{n!}.$$

I am looking for the change of variable leading from the first to the second form. I attempted $y_i:=1-\sum_{j=i}^n x_j$, but indeed did not work.

How would you do this?

Comment: I think [this is what you're looking for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Increasing_coordinates), other than their $s_j$ variables being in the opposite order of your $y_j$ variables.

Comment: Hello, the reason such that I don't like much that transform it is because I feel that the integral of the generic $s_i$ wouldn't be between $0$ and $s_{i+1}$ but istead over $[s_{i-1},s_{i+1}]$. Why is it between 0 and $s_i$?